# Hibernate-mapping (XML) an abstract class

Tags: hibernate, javafx, abstract-class, hibernate-mapping

Good Day, everyone!

I have 2 classes: `AstractClass` and `SimpleClass`, which is extended by `AbstractClas`s. Also I have just 1 table in my database, it is `SimpleClass's` table with all extended fields and its own fields.

So, can you tell me, how many `*.hbm.xml` files should I create? And how to show this abstract connection in my `SimpleClass`?

P.S. The main condition is not to use annotations, just creation of xml-files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it will help others.

So, I created hbm.xml file for my `SimpleClass`'s table, where I described all references, including fields from my `AbstractClass`.